# Java regex: [^(\\s?-\\s?)]. PatternSyntaxException on 's'?

Tags: java, regex, string, patternsyntaxexception

I just started learning java regex today so excuse me for taking a rather lazy approach to learning what's wrong with my regex. Basically I'm trying to split a string on 'white space', -, 'white space' pattern (where white space is either one or none) and I'm not sure why the pattern isn't compiling. I get an error on the second s in: [^(\s?-\s?)] (index 8). If someone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: What are `[]` meant for in a regular expression?

Comment: I wish I could answer this question but I'm not even sure why I used it haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are placing your pattern you are trying to split on inside of a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in which it is doing the exact opposite of what you are expecting it to do.

```
[^(\s?-\s?)]  # matches any character except: 

                  # '('
                  # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") 
                  # '?'
                  # '-'
                  # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                  # '?'
                  # ')'
```

Your syntax is indeed incorrect, but **`why will it not compile?`** Well, Inside of a character class the hyphen has **special** meaning. You can place a hyphen as the first or last character of the class. In some regular expression implementations, you can also place directly after a range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to escape it in order to add it to your class.

To **fix the compile issue**, you would simply escape the hyphen, still this regex does not do what you want.

> I'm trying to split a string on **white space, `-`, white space pattern**...

Remove the character class and the capturing group from the pattern:

```
String s = "foo - bar - baz-quz";
String[] parts = s.split("\\s?-\\s?");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts)); //=> [foo, bar, baz, quz]
```

Here are a few references for learning regular expressions.

- [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [RexEgg - Tutorial](http://www.rexegg.com/)

Comment: Thanks m8. You answered this question like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

\s is a character class. Characters inside [] are treated as those characters. (Or not specific characters in the case of [^]). It doesn't make sense to use \s inside of [].

Perhaps you mean to use parenthesis instead of braces?

Comment: The parenthesis allow the expression to compile, but the intended effect isn't there... Any ideas?